# Backbone: grab new model from server before adding to collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently when I make a model it goes straight to the collection and saves to the server, but the server adds additional information model that isn't seen until the page is refreshed. I'm trying to add the new model to the collection from the server and not from the form that makes the model.

This is my add method

```
add:function(tenant){
    var values = _.extend(this.$el.find(':input').serializeJSON(), {active: true , modelType:"tenant"}) 

    console.log(values)
    var newView = tenants.create(values, {// FIX REPONCE 
        success:function(model,response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(model.isNew());
        },
        error:function(model,response){
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    },{wait: true},{silent: true})
}
```

When it hits the model.IsNew(), it returns true which means it didn't hit the server yet. How can I return the server model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collection.create`'s second argument is `options`, but you passed options `{wait: true}` and `{silent: true}` as the third and fourth arguments respectively. That's why they take no effect. Try this:

```
var newView = tenants.create(values, {
    wait: true,
    silent: true,
    success:function(model,response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(model.isNew());
    },
    error:function(model,response){
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: In noticed that and changed it but it still has the same result for the model not hitting the server first.

Comment: @delboud That's no surprise to me, since even without passing {wait: true} to the `create`, the model passed to the `success` callback function should come from the server. You may need check whether the response data returned from the sever is correct or not(e.g make sure that model's id is *NOT* `null`). If response is correct while model.isNew() == true, you may need exam model's `parse` method(if it has been overridden).